# Converting dd/MM/yyyy input to yyyy-MM-dd in date format not varchar/datetime

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, date, type-conversion

After searching for a full day, I'm unable to find a solution, facing multiple conversion errors. Main objective is to convert a `dd/MM/yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` "date" format to fit in SQL Server.

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with datatype `date` as a column in my table.

I'm using a jQuery datepicker with jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js on my project website that outputs `dd/MM/yyyy` which is obtained using

```
Dim dDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form(txtStart.UniqueID))
```

Then I'm attempting to do an insert SQL using the date obtained but the database date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(DATETIME, '14/10/2011', 0), 120)
```

Tried this and it works but it's of `varchar` data type which is not what I need

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '15/4/2014', 111), '/', '-')  AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
```

I really need a code either on my website VB/C# code or SQL statement whichever to fulfill this please help

My script using the jQuery has already written in code the format that my sql is currently set, however at runtime it does not apply

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtStart.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: false,
        ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d ",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Main objective is to convert a dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd "date" format to fit in SQL

Don't! You should avoid string conversions as far as you possibly can. Keep your data in its natural representation for as much of the time as you can.

You may well need to parse the date from `dd/MM/yyyy` to `DateTime` to start with (although if you can avoid even this, do so - we don't know where your data comes from), but then you should *leave* it as a `DateTime`. Use parameterized SQL instead, passing the value of the parameter to the database as a `DateTime`. Of course, you should *also* make sure that the fields in your database are using the appropriate type to start with (not `varchar`). Ensuring that your schema matches your data is crucial to running a sane system.

The parsing part should be relatively simple. For example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You *may* want to use a user's culture instead (depending on where the data has come from) and you *may* want to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead (if this is user-entered data rather than something from machine-to-machine communication).

Comment: Thanks i'll look into this once again as I've already tried .parseExact and it gives me a compile error. You have a point in retaining its dateformat

Comment: @user2552331: If it gives a compilation error (rather than an exception) then you probably don't have a string to start with... you should update your question with what you've tried and the *exact* error. Note that I've given code in C#, whereas your question uses VB... hopefully you can convert my C# into VB easily enough.

Comment: have tried and gave me an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." `Dim dDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form(txtStart.UniqueID).ToString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: not sure if this has got to do with the fact that the way i'm obtaining the date time is by using a jquery datetimepicker

Comment: @user2552331: An exception isn't the same as a compile-time error, and we can't help without knowing what the value actually *was*. All of this information (including the part about the jquery datetimepicker, and the value which is failing) should be in the *question*, not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that there is no format for `DateTime`.if you want convert some date string into DateTime and if you know the Date format upfront  you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()`

Try This:

```
string strDate = "21/04/2014";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate,"dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

now you can store the DateTime variable `dt` into database but if you want to display the DateTime in some format ex:yyyy-MM-dd you need to call `ToString()` as below

```
String datetime = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: seems like i get a runtime error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @user2552331: are you trying my code? can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dateFormat` option

```
$(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });
```

DEMO [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WArtA/)

Comment: Does this mean I have to replace my <script></script> information and use your coding? I just copied and couldnt understand from another source.

Comment: When you are using datepicker in javascript so why are you don't use javascript date format.

Comment: I've already specified the format of date that i want, the problem is when the retrieved date is actually showing dd/MM/yyyy when it reaches the SQL query..

Comment: Now are you happy :):):)

Comment: sorry .. I tried the code but it seems like its for java and not applicable in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

we can try ParseExact method while using InvariantCulture. This provides information about a specific culture. The information includes the names for the culture,the writing system( yyyy-MM-dd in your case) etc.

```
        String MyDateString;
        DateTime MyDateTime;

          MyDateString = txtDateOfIncidence.Text.Trim()+ " " + txtTiming.Text.Trim();
          MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "yyyy/MM/dd" + " hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```