# Convert datetime to a special format in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, converters

I need a Function to get date like this : 2015/09/19

And convert the date to a format like this : 19 November 2015

Comment: clearly mention that you want to convert from 2015/09/24 to 19 November 2015

Comment: Look at `format()`. Your style will be something like `'dd MMMM yyyy'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dd/MM/yyyy input to yyyy-MM-dd in date format not varchar/datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194700/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-input-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-date-format-not-varchar-datetime)

Comment: Just a nit pick `09` is `September` not `November`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @MyDate AS Date='2015/09/24'
SELECT DATENAME(DD ,@MyDate)+' '+
       DATENAME(MONTH ,@MyDate)+' '+
       DATENAME(YEAR ,@MyDate) AS [OutputDate]
```

OR

```
SELECT FORMAT(@MyDate ,'dd MMMM yyyy') AS [OutputDate]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)

Comment: @HengamehVlizadeh -you are welcome. have a great time ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [FORMAT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
DECLARE @x AS Date='2015/09/24'
SELECT FORMAT(@x ,'dd MMMM yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106);

SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM dd yyyy');

SELECT  CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
       + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month dd yyyy]
```

Comment: Its November not Nov!

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM DD YYYY');` the output would be `November DD YYYY`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)